# Setting up Angular Universal App for development

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular-universal

I have created a project with Angular-CLI. (using command: `ng new my-angular-universal`).
Then I carefully followed all the instructions from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

It builds for `--prod` and works fine. But there are no instructions on how I can set up a `--dev` build and have it served with `--watch` flag.

I tried removing `--prod` flags from npm "scripts", and it doesn't even run in dev mode. It builds fine but when I open it in browser this is what I see (directly printed to response):

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Mikser\documents\git\my-angular-universal\dist\server.js:7069:134
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\Users\Mikser\documents\git\my-angular-universal\dist\server.js:105076:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (C:\Users\Mikser\documents\git\my-angular-universal\dist\server.js:6328:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\Users\Mikser\documents\git\my-angular-universal\dist\server.js:105075:32)
    at Zone.run (C:\Users\Mikser\documents\git\my-angular-universal\dist\server.js:104826:43)
    at NgZone.run (C:\Users\Mikser\documents\git\my-angular-universal\dist\server.js:6145:69)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (C:\Users\Mikser\documents\git\my-angular-universal\dist\server.js:7068:23)
    at Object.renderModuleFactory (C:\Users\Mikser\documents\git\my-angular-universal\dist\server.js:52132:39)
    at View.engine (C:\Users\Mikser\documents\git\my-angular-universal\dist\server.js:104656:23)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Mikser\documents\git\my-angular-universal\dist\server.js:130741:8)
```

the versions of npm packages that I use are currently the latest:

- @angular/* - @5.2.*
- @angular/cli @1.7.3

except for ts-loader, had to downgrade it because it wasn't working:

- ts-loader @3.5.0

So if anyone has any info on how to make this work, it would be very appreciated! Or maybe you know some project templates with Angular Universal App configured for both `--dev` and `--prod` builds and ability to `--watch`?

Comment: This means you'd need to build with watch 3 things, right: client bundle, server bundle and also rebuild server.js/ts ?

Comment: It seems so. But I have difficulty understanding why server bundle and server.ts code are treated separately.

Comment: What really helps me to understand Angular Universal and all the build steps was to watch this Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDasXnb6EFI. I can highly recommend to watch it and follow all steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As contributors have pointed out, it might not be the most efficient and fastest way to develop, but nevertheless I did not want to accept workarounds. Besides, hosting front and back on separate servers brings up CORS issues, and I never planned my app to run on separate hosts, I wanted it all on the same host together with API methods.

**The problem with `--dev` build was this:**

when building with the following command:

`ng build --app 1 --output-hashing=false` (note that there is no `--prod` flag)

`AppServerModuleNgFactory` turned out missing in the `./dist-server/main.bundle`

I imagine that this relates to the ahead of time(`--aot`) compilation which is the default behavior if you are building for `--prod`. So the instructions from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering included instructions to configure express server for production build only. And since there is no need for server to be able to dynamically render html templates the working `--dev` build command would be:

`ng build --app 1 --output-hashing=false --aot`

and this gets rid of the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined`

**Now to watch this whole mess:**

run these in separate command windows:

1. `ng build --watch`
2. `ng build --app 1 --output-hashing=false --aot --watch`
3. `webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors --watch`

And for the server to restart on change, you have to install `nodemon` package and run it like this:

4. `nodemon --inspect dist/server` (`--inspect` if you wish to debug server with chrome)

**Some other important stuff:**

Angular/CLI has a command to generate necessary scaffolding for a universal app:

`ng generate universal`

and it generates a fixed version of `main.ts` that avoids [client angular bootstrap issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20484):
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
});`

a problem that I stumbled upon once I implemented `TransferState`

Comment: I believe you that this worked when you wrote this. But for now, despite the provided watch commands seeming to do everything correctly, no changes get reflected anywhere until I explicitly run `build:ssr` and `serve:ssr`. `ng serve` and other commands do nothing either, and in fact produce blank white pages.

Answer (score 3):

For development, run `npm run start` which triggers `ng serve`. The current setup has hot module reloading so it will watch for your changes and update your dev view. I used the same instructions and got it working here https://github.com/ariellephan/angular5-universal-template

In short, for development, run `npm run start` and look at `http://localhost:4200`.

For production, run `npm run build:ssr` and `npm run serve:ssr`and look at `http://localhost:4000`

Comment: I really wish this worked :( but one of universal's dependencies, `domino`, errors out with `ng serve` as the `'use strict'` instructions peppered everywhere don't like the use of that modules `which` :|

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two parts - the server and the UI. While developing the UI, I simply use `ng serve`. That means when I make changes in my code in the IDE, the browser refreshes automatically. And, here the server part is not used.

I do prod build and run the server only for final testing to see if everything works as expected (No error due to any 3PP library DOM manipulation or AOT related issues, etc.)

[Here](https://github.com/saptarshibasu/angular-universal-setup), I have created a skeleton structure of an Angular Universal project. As I extensively use Vagrant and Docker in my projects, I run the server in a Docker container within the Vagrant guest system. And for development of the UI, I don't run the server. Simply, the `ng serve` is used.

If you look into my structure in the above Github link, you'll find the details as to how to run it for development and production in the Readme file.

Comment: You need to add the flag --live-reload to auto reload the web if you made changes.

Answer (score 0):

The web server handler `server.ts` uses the server bundle

```
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');
```

That's why the server bundle needs to be compiled before you can compile the `server.ts` file.

So having a watch system would mean

- watching/recompiling the client bundle
- watching/recompiling the server bundle
- recompiling the `server.ts` once the server bundle is created

All of them take some time (especially if you do it with aot)

I'd recommend, like Saptarshi Basu mentionned, to develop as best as you can with `ng serve` and check with angular universal every so often.

Otherwise, it should be possible do achieve what you want with some kind of tasks (grunt/gulp/...) which triggers sequentially `ng build ...` and recompilation of `server.ts` file.

Comment: turns out that when I build in `--dev` mode `AppServerModuleNgFactory` is completely missing in the server/main.bundle. That is probably why I get this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined error`. Any idea why it is missing in a non-`--prod` build?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit messy no doubt, as we preferably wish for one command to rule them all.
I came up with a somewhat OK solution where my output will be:
dist/browser
dist/ng-server

Using the executable npm-run-all package (I find it working a lot better on windows machines than concurrently does) I run the three watch tasks: browser, ng-server and nodeJS. Watching node has a pre-task defined that simply runs a small utility/helper/file that watches for the existence of a dist/ng-server folder and terminate itself once found.

For all of this to work (based on the universal-starter repo as of november 2018) there's a couple of modifications to package.json  required. Primarily, to support the --watch flag on ng run commands we need to update the compiler-cli (if memory serves), ng update --all should take care of that, giving you the latest angular/cli version in the process (assuming you have a recent cli version installed globally).

### package.json

1. ng update --all

   - angular 6+
   - angular/cli 7+
2. yarn add/npm install the following

   - chokidar
   - npm-run-all
     (runs our tasks in parallel with the -p flag. -p kills all processes, -l gives each running task a specific color and name in the console)
   - ts-node (runs nodejs in it's ts-format)
   - nodemon // for restarting ts-node
3. add something similar to my util/await-file.js (after some consideration I added my own file-watcher code below even though it wasn't exactly written with the intentions to be put up on display...)
4. modify your package.json scripts like below
5. modify your angular.json to match your folder names, following my examples, mainly the "server"'s outputPath should be changed from dist/server to dist/ng-server.

package.json scripts

```
"dev": "npm-run-all -p -r -l watch:ng-server watch:browser watch:node",
"watch:browser": "ng build --prod --progress --watch --delete-output-path",
"watch:ng-server": "ng run ng-universal-demo:server --watch --delete-output-path",
"watch:node": "yarn run watch:file-exist && yarn run ts-node",
"ts-node": "nodemon --exec ts-node server.ts -e ts,js",
"watch:file-exist": "node utils/await-file.js",
```

util/await-file.js

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const DIR_NAME = 'ng-server';

const DIST_PATH = './dist';

// creates dist folder if it doesn't exist - prior to adding it to the watcher.
if (!fs.existsSync(DIST_PATH)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(DIST_PATH);
}

const watcher = chokidar.watch('file, dir', {
  ignored: '*.map',
  persistent: true,
  awaitWriteFinish: {
    stabilityThreshold: 5000,
    pollInterval: 100
  }
});

const FOLDER_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
watcher.add(FOLDER_PATH);

console.log(`file-watcher running, waiting for ${DIST_PATH}/${DIR_NAME}`);

function fileFound() {
  console.log(`${DIR_NAME} folder found - closing`);
  watcher.close();
  process.exit();
}

watcher
  .on('add', function (filePath) {
    const matchWith = path.join('dist', DIR_NAME);
    const paths = filePath.split(path.sep);
    const fileName = paths[paths.length - 1];
    if ((filePath.indexOf(matchWith) >= 0)
      && fileName.indexOf('.js') > fileName.length - 4) {
      fileFound();
    }
  })
  .on('error', error => console.log(`Watcher error: ${error}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

"npm run start" and using "http://localhost:4200" works for me. Even with Angular 10